# Can I update my existing Android and iOS app with freshly made app on React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to update my existing IOS and Android app, which is developed native on swift and java, i want to update it with new version made in react native can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

On android, yes.  So long as it has the same signing key and the version code has increased, it can be updated with any valid apk.

Comment: thanks, can it be possible on IOS too cause i have IOS too

Comment: Not absolutely certain as I don't do iOS, but I would expect so.  I'd be very surprised if it didn't.

Comment: its giving me error "App not installed" error: an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed , my aplication keystore and password is same as the previous application which is live, can you help me with this

Comment: Conflicting signature means you didn't use the same keystore.